# Haskell Diagrams: Why does text not have length or width?

Tags: haskell, haskell-diagrams

I would like to create a text box that I can set to have a particular width and height. However, the text box that I create appears to not have a width and height in the first place. E.g. the following code:

```
main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ width $ myText
  putStrLn $ show $ height $ myText
  mainWith myText

myText :: Diagram B
myText = text "here" # lw 1 # fontSizeL 0.2 # fc grey # scaleX 1
```

results in a blank diagram (with no text), and prints "0.0" as the width and height of the text box:

```
ghc --make Main.hs && ./Main -o circle.svg -w 400
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking Main ...
0.0
0.0
```

---

In order to get the text to appear it seem that I need to place it on top of something else. E.g. the following code:

```
main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ width $ myDiagram 
  putStrLn $ show $ height $ myDiagram
  mainWith myDiagram

myDiagram :: Diagram B
myDiagram = myText <> myBackground

myText :: Diagram B
myText = text "here" # lw 1 # fontSizeL 0.2 # fc grey # scaleX 1

myBackground :: Diagram B
myBackground = rect 1 1 # fc black
```

produces the grey text within a black background as expected.

---

Why does the text box not have a size?

How can I set the length and width of a text box to a certain value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the text box not have a size?

Because text handling is not only highly dependent on the backend used to render the diagrams (cf. [the User's Guide](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/manual.html#text)) but also potentially dependent on how fonts are configured in the system used to run the program.

> How can I set the length and width of a text box to a certain value?

1. Use text handling functions provided by your chosen backend, if they exist. For instance, *diagrams-cairo* provides [functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-cairo-1.3.1.2/docs/Diagrams-Backend-Cairo-Text.html) that use Pango to render text on its own, though with the significant annoyance of them being `IO` functions, as they need to query font information from the system.
2. Use [*SVGFonts*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SVGFonts-1.6.0.0/docs/Graphics-SVGFonts.html) to stroke the text independently of the backend. There are a few inconveniences with this approach as well (limited choice of fonts unless you follow the instructions in the documentation to convert your chosen font to the SVGFonts format yourself; fonts with large sets of characters might lead to a small but noticeable delay when they are first used by your program, as they have to go through an initial processing), but at least you don't have to bother with `IO` or backend-specific quirks.

Comment: SVGFonts with scaleUToX is working well to set the width of text. Thanks for the answer!